# Is there a way to simplify document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

My javascript code is exceeding 3000 thousand lines of code because I need to call many variables, is there any way to simplify this?

Here's the code:

```
var Start = document.getElementById('Start'),
    question1 = document.getElementById('1'),
    question2 = document.getElementById('2'),
    question3 = document.getElementById('3'),
    question4 = document.getElementById('4'),
    question5 = document.getElementById('5'),
    question6 = document.getElementById('6'),
    question7 = document.getElementById('7');
```

I have more than 50 variables to questions and more 50 to answers.

Comment: You can use loops and arrays.

Comment: Can you give an example? I have no idea how to do this... (I tried)

Comment: What is your HTML like? If they all share a class it's easier to use `document.querySelectorAll('.questionClass')` – the `for` loop answers are good, but require you to know the number of questions and use numeric ids.

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML? Using `id` attributes in this way is completely unnecessary and wasteful. You should be using `HTMLCollection`s with loops - not individual calls to `.getElementByid()`

Comment: Recommending `HTMLCollections` is just asking for confusion as they are live, `NodeLists` are more predictable (mostly).

Comment: @RandyCasburn—without knowing the OP's requirements, you don't know if id's are "completely unnecessary" or not. A NodeList or collection provides access only by list index, there may be requirements to access by other means, e.g. an ID might provide a reference to the associated answer.

Comment: @RobG - Most "requirements" to include `id` attributes are flawed in the first place due to the lack of forethought about HTML 5 custom data- attributes. I'll agree that we don't know the requirements, but will not agree about the need for a static `id` attribute value that is numeric and sequential.

Comment: having to use so many IDs for similar elements shows that your HTML structure is poorly done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a single array variable for keeping all questions instead of individual variables:

```
// initialize a variable to be an empty array
var questions = [];

// create a loop which assigns value 1 to 9 into the variable i
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    // assign the content of the element with ID i to i-th element of the array
    questions[i] = document.getElementById(i);
}
```

Then, you can use for example `questions[5]` instead of `question5`.

In case you have a non-sequential naming of HTML elements, you may use an array containing a list of element IDs:

```
// define a list of element IDs
let htmlIds = ['id1', 'ab', 'xy', 'anotherId'];

// initialize a variable to be an empty array
var questions = [];

// go through all items of the htmlIds arrays and populate questions
htmlIds.forEach(item => questions[item] = item);
```

But I would consider a different approach in such case, you can ignore the IDs and query the questions for example using a class as PHP Guru mentions in his answer.

Comment: This will help a lot! But I also have questions that the Id is not a number in the sequence, like "10, 11, 12 ..." Some questions, the Id has to be "SR1, SN1, SR2 ..." Is there a way to use the same logic ?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer. You simply have to manually define a list of element IDs first.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can use a loop and an array:

```
let questions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  questions.push(document.getElementById(i));
}
```

You loop through a certain suitable range -- and append to the array in each iteration.

Then, you can access a particular "question" like this:

```
console.log(questions[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `class="question"` to every question instead of `id=1`, `id=2`, etc., and then use `document.querySelectorAll(".question")` to get an array like object containing all of the questions on the page.

```
var questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question");
// now you can reference every question with questions[0] thru questions[n-1]
```